# Android GCM: Not getting registration token on onCreate() method

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging, android-notifications

I am embedding GCM for push notification in my app. I'm facing a very weird problem, on first run I'm not able to get GCM registration token, but when you run my app second time you will get the registration ID printing on the console. I don't know what am I doing worng. Here is what I have done so far.

This is my onCreate() method where I want to print GCM regID:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    final String regId = GCMRegistrar.getRegistrationId(this);
    GCM_regID = regId;
            System.out.println("GCM regId: "+GCM_regID);
```

Doing the following code inside onCreate():

```
/**
     * Google Cloud Messaging - Getting server Url and device ID to send it
     * across Google server for the notification..
     */
    mGCMReceiver = new GCMReceiver();
    mOnRegisteredFilter = new IntentFilter();
    mOnRegisteredFilter.addAction(Constants.ACTION_ON_REGISTERED);

    if (Constants.SENDER_ID == null) {
        // mStatus.setText("Missing SENDER_ID");
        return;
    }
    if (Constants.SERVER_URL == null) {
        // mStatus.setText("Missing SERVER_URL");
        return;
    }

    GCMRegistrar.checkDevice(this);
    GCMRegistrar.checkManifest(this);

    if (!regId.equals("")) {
        sendIdToServer(regId);
    } else {
        GCMRegistrar.register(getApplicationContext(), Constants.SENDER_ID);
    }

    sendIdToServer(regId);

}
```

Sending GCM_regId to server via these method as guided in one of the tutorial:

```
/**
 * GCM - sending the data in json format to server db
 * */
public void sendIdToServer(String regId) {
    (new SendRegistrationIdTask(regId)).execute();
    GCM_regID = regId;
}

private class GCMReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String regId = intent
                .getStringExtra(Constants.FIELD_REGISTRATION_ID);
        token = regId;

    }
}

private final class SendRegistrationIdTask extends
        AsyncTask<String, Void, HttpResponse> {
    // private String mRegId;

    public SendRegistrationIdTask(String regId) {
        // mRegId = regId;
    }

    @Override
    protected HttpResponse doInBackground(String... regIds) {
        // String url = Constants.SERVER_URL + "/register";

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(HttpResponse response) {
        if (response == null) {

            return;
        }

        StatusLine httpStatus = response.getStatusLine();
        if (httpStatus.getStatusCode() != 200) {
            Log.e(Constants.TAG, "Status: " + httpStatus.getStatusCode());
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

I don't think so, GCMIntentService class is needed here for my problem. Please look into this and help me in getting out of this issue.

I'm able to print in GCMIntentService class, on onRegistered(). Here it goes:

```
@Override
protected void onRegistered(Context context, String regId) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Constants.ACTION_ON_REGISTERED);
    intent.putExtra(Constants.FIELD_REGISTRATION_ID, regId);
    context.sendBroadcast(intent);
}
```

I have to print the regId on MainActivity, on onCreate().

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Registering the device will take some time.. So if you will try to retrieve the registration id immediately after registering the device in onCreate() then every time it will return a null value.. So try to register your device inside onCreate() and retrieve the id in any different activity/Service (You can retrieve the Id from GCMIntentService class the api from GCM). Note method of GCM Intent Service class.

```
    protected void onRegistered(Context arg0, String arg1) {
    Logger.d(arg0, "REG ID="+arg1);
    regID = arg1;
}
```

This is method is called after Reg is done.
So for my case the regID i took this as a static string and am accessing it else.
OR Like u want the regID on Activity B it is preferred to Register it on Activity A and retrieve it via the static string in the above method from the GCMIntent Class.

Comment: I'm getting the value on GCMIntentService, so how to get that value in the MainActivity. I have tried doing that but didn't work for me.

Comment: In GCMIntentService override the onRegistered() method, and your value comes in the parameter like for the above in String arg1. Simply print it.

Comment: Take a static string equate that with it and access that string in ur class.

Comment: Tnx, you are right. If I wait some time, that i retrieve the registration id

Answer (score 1):

The reason that you are not getting the regID the first time you run your app is because your app does not have a regID yet, it needs to ask the GCM servers for it. So when you call `final String regId = GCMRegistrar.getRegistrationId(this);` the first time it will return an empty string. However once you have been registered with GCM the next time you make that call (the next time your app starts) your regID will be returned. The GCM jar simply stores the regID as a string in the app prefs.

When the GCM servers register your device, you will know about it when `GCMIntentService.OnRegistered()` is called. In your code you are broadcasting an intent with your regID in the `GCMIntentService.OnRegistered()` which I assume you want to handle with your `GCMReceiver` (?) although in the code sample you have shown I do not see you creating an instance of the class or registering it as a receiver.

What I think you will want to in `GCMReceiver.onReceive()` is call `sendIdToServer()` with the regID that you got from the intent. e.g.

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    String regId = intent
            .getStringExtra(Constants.FIELD_REGISTRATION_ID);
    Log.i("regID: ", regId);
    sendIdToServer(regId);
}
```

We have a [GCM/Airbop client sample](https://github.com/indigorose/airbop-client) that you might want to look at. It is based on the [GCM Demo app](http://code.google.com/p/gcm/) which you **should** take a look at.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not logged into a Google account in the emulator will not work. Try logging in with a valid account of Google ( gmail ) and see .